# PHP Avoid to repeat the same try catch

Tags: php, refactoring

I'm using PHP 7 with Phalcon 3. I'd like to implement Stripe response in one function. I can handle errors like [that](https://stripe.com/docs/api/errors/handling?lang=php).

Here is the code:

```
try {
  // Use Stripe's library to make requests...
} catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
  // Since it's a decline, \Stripe\Error\Card will be caught
  $body = $e->getJsonBody();
  $err  = $body['error'];

  print('Status is:' . $e->getHttpStatus() . "\n");
  print('Type is:' . $err['type'] . "\n");
  print('Code is:' . $err['code'] . "\n");
  // param is '' in this case
  print('Param is:' . $err['param'] . "\n");
  print('Message is:' . $err['message'] . "\n");
} catch (\Stripe\Error\RateLimit $e) {
  // Too many requests made to the API too quickly
} catch (\Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest $e) {
  // Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe's API
} catch (\Stripe\Error\Authentication $e) {
  // Authentication with Stripe's API failed
  // (maybe you changed API keys recently)
} catch (\Stripe\Error\ApiConnection $e) {
  // Network communication with Stripe failed
} catch (\Stripe\Error\Base $e) {
  // Display a very generic error to the user, and maybe send
  // yourself an email
} catch (Exception $e) {
  // Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe
}
```

Each time I need to call a Stripe method I need to implement all this try catch. How can I do to create one function with all Stripe exceptions ? I got the idea to send stripe function in parameter and use the function in the try but it doesn't work because the function is executed before to be inside the function.

```
  function stripeResponse($function) {
    try {
      // Use Stripe's library to make requests...
      \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("my_key");
      $function();
    } catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
      // Since it's a decline, \Stripe\Error\Card will be caught
    } catch (\Stripe\Error\RateLimit $e) {
      // Too many requests made to the API too quickly
    } catch (\Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest $e) {
      // Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe's API
    } catch (\Stripe\Error\Authentication $e) {
      // Authentication with Stripe's API failed
      // (maybe you changed API keys recently)
    } catch (\Stripe\Error\ApiConnection $e) {
      // Network communication with Stripe failed
    } catch (\Stripe\Error\Base $e) {
      // Display a very generic error to the user, and maybe send
      // yourself an email
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      // Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe
    }
  }

    return $this->stripeResponse(\Stripe\Charge::create([
        "amount" => 100,
        "currency" => "eur",
        "source" => "token",
        "description" => "Description"
    ]));
```

Do you have an idea to do what I want ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you are calling `$this->stripeResponse` is incorrect. You are passing it the response of `\Stripe\Charge::create` instead of a callable.

You can change it to:

```
return $this->stripeResponse(function() {
    \Stripe\Charge::create([
        "amount" => 100,
        "currency" => "eur",
        "source" => "token",
        "description" => "Description"
    ]);
});
```